# Visual Studio Configuraiton manager Deploy column disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, deployment, configurationmanager

I am having a problem with the configuration manager in Visual Studio 2013.  The Deploy column is disabled no.  The only thing I did was a Repair of Visual Studio 2013 and not my WebAPI project not longer has the Deploy option enabled in Configuration Manager.  I used to be able to do a file system deploy to the folder on the Web Server that hosted my WebAPI process.  I am not sure what is going on.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

FYI - The CGSAPI project type is class library but that is what it has always been.

[image: Configuration Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I was just being silly.  I have to right mouse button click on the actual WebAPI project and Publish will be available in the dropdown list. :)